# Whole page refresh in jasp page

Tags: java, jsp

I created jsp page,In that i created 2 input boxes and to & from field for calender,if i enter list will display in the same page .after if i click clear button it should remove all the content in the page how can I do.I used bellow to code but not getting to clear whole page content.

```
<input type="reset" name="clear" value="Clear"  /> and 

<input type="button" value="Reload Page" onClick="document.location.reload(true)">
```

both i tried

Thanks
svn

Comment: type="reset" just resets the forms, not clear the whole page
And your code is not complete enough to understand ur problem

Comment: can you please be a little more specific what you want , what i understood , i can tell you to use a java script function to set the values to null or empty onclick on your clear button and to render the same page on submit , give the same jsp page in the action of the form  of your jsp page

Answer (score 1):

By list, you mean results of the date search? And you wish to clear the results on click of a button? Wrap the results section in a  layer and on click of the button, write a function that will hide the div layer -document.getElementById("yourDivId").style.display="none"